# ServiceActivationException: Request cannot be dispatched because the virtual application is shutting down

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

We are having a problem with our virtual application shutting down.   Site is running ASP.NET 4.5

**Exception summary:**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Request to the service at '~/Services/ServiceExceptionLogger.svc' cannot be dispatched because the virtual application at '/Site' is shutting down.
```

**Stack trace:**

```
System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: Request to the service at 
'~/Services/ServiceExceptionLogger.svc' cannot be dispatched because the virtual application
 at '/Site' is shutting down. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Request to the service at '~/Services/ServiceExceptionLogger.svc' cannot be dispatched because the virtual 
application at '/Site' is shutting down.
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
```

Or here is another version of it that shows up in the event logs

**Stack Trace:**

```
System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: Request to the service at '~/Services/Service.svc' cannot be dispatched because the virtual application at '/Site' is shutting down. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Request to the service at '~/Services/Service.svc' cannot be dispatched because the virtual application at '/Site' is shutting down.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
```

Anyone have any ideas or seen this before?  Seems to happen quite frequently on one of our environments, like 10+ times a day.  On the QA environment its not happening at all.  Idle timeout is set to 20minutes on both environments.  Reason for 20 minute timeout is to avoid wasted memory

Update 1: Found some supplementary information on logging app pool recycles here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17630/which-event-log-file-does-iis-7-app-pool-log-to/17633#17633?newreg=d562bf378cc545b49a7ea8f2a3c1b48d

Update 2: Apparently the app pool is not recycling when the above exception occurs.  We are watching the process in task manager and it is not shutting down or reducing the memory when this exception occurs.  Also, no log entry occurs (see update 1) when this exception happens

Comment: How often does this happen? what do your IIS logs say at these times? is your application pool re-starting when this happens?

Comment: Ma_Khan added more details to the question. I have to check the IIS logs to see if anything is in there.

Comment: Another good place to check would be the event logs... IIS always makes log entry whenever an app pool recycles ... so that should give you a hint or a timeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After escalating this to Microsoft support, we think this issue is a bug .NET 4.5.1. It happens most often when running in integrated mode, but also occurs in classic mode, although much less frequently.  We haven't been able to pinpoint the actual case or problem but it doesn't seem to be occuring on older .NET runtimes.

Comment: We see the same behavior, a couple of times per year in automated tests, and are similarly baffled by it.  Our first recorded occurrence of this problem is from December 24, 2013.  And I just checked, and noticed that .NET 4.5.1 was installed on that system on November 21, 2013.  So that is a consistent explanation.  Thanks for posting!

Comment: What did you end up doing? Upgrade to 4.5.2?

Comment: It was 3 years ago. Don't recall now. :(

Comment: @Sameer: It is very annoying. It re-occurs even after I restarted IIS.

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming** this is what you are experiencing:

In IIS, Application Pools recycle themselves every ~20 minutes (I don't remember the exact default time) after inactivity.

This is changeable though in the IIS Manager under the "Advanced Settings" for your App Pool.

Comment: Yes this is probably the issue, while the app pool is recycling, its making a request and failing.  However, not quite sure why this suddenly came up and how to fix it

Comment: Zach, when we put the idle timeout to 120, the problem happens much less often.  But we want it to be closer to 20

Comment: Zach, thank you for your help.  We use a different app pool for each site (for security or what not).  So it causes a waste of memory to have a long idle timeout

Comment: Zach I put another update, apparently it doesnt look like its actually recycling, the exception says the application is shutting down but there is no evidence to indicate it really did shut down.  Strange or what